# Run External Python script outside the Django project through html button

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am trying to run python script through html button but I am getting the following error. I don't know why. kindly help to get rid off it. The error is:

**module 'sys' has no attribute 'execute'**

views.py:

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import sys
def external(request):
 
  out = run([sys.execute,'/home/abc/Documents/test.py'], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
  print(out)

  return render(request, 'home.html', {{'data1': out}})
```

home.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> RUN PYTHON SCRIPT </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action='{% url "external" %}' method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" name="btn" value="start analyse" id="toggle1" onclick="location.href='{% url 'external' %}'" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

urls.py:

```
 path('external/', views.external, name="external"),
```

Even the button doesn't execute the test.py python script and gives the following error:
**module 'sys' has no object 'execute' in views.py**

kindly help me to run script through html button

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) library like

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["ls", "-l", "/dev/null"], capture_output=True)
```

Comment: dear @Ajay k, have an eye on this question also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74275330/how-to-save-file-in-two-different-directories-after-uploading-a-file-in-django

Comment: may i know your use case? why you want to upload the same file in multiple directories?

Comment: Use case is that I want a text file to analyze by using different modules. One of these modules use the text file included in his directory. I can't change the path as It configurations may change and can't run the script. Therefore, I want to upload file in different directories

Answer (score 0):

try to change forme line like this:
`<form action="/external" method="post">`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).